# setup.py nosetests command throws ImportError when specifying package_dir

Tags: python, setuptools, nose, software-distribution

When setup.py specifies a package_dir different from the package name, the setup.py nosetests function fails due to an ImportError. Following is a minimal example.

directory structure:

```
setup.py
src/
    __init__.py
    myclass.py
unittests/
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

The init files are empty. MyClass is trivial:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__():
        a=10
```

The test.py just instantiates an instance of myclass:

```
import unittest
import mypkg

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def _run_test(self):
        a = mypkg.myclass()
```

And the setup.py file is as follows

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'mypkg',
    packages = ['mypkg'],
    package_dir={'mypkg':'src'}
    )
```

It builds and installs correctly, but before installation you get:

```
python3.4 setup.py nosetests
running nosetests
running egg_info
writing top-level names to mypkg.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mypkg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing mypkg.egg-info/PKG-INFO
reading manifest file 'mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named 'mypkg')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
          :
          :
          :
  File "<root_dir>/unittests/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mypkg
ImportError: No module named 'mypkg'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.026s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've chased it back and am pretty sure this happens because in setup.py I effectively rename a directory through the use of package_dir. Is there some trick to making nosetests work without changing my directory structure?

Note: this was run using python3.4 with setuptools version 2.1 and nosetests version 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

hi you have to specify the py file that contain mypkg maybe :

```
from yourfile import mypkg
```

Thanks

Comment: That would work only if the files weren't being moved around by the setuptools installation process...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it, although it isn't very pretty...
But here goes:

One way to make sure that nosetests actually has access to everything is to build before you run nosetests. The Nosetests command for setuptools will actually do this, but if it can it is lazy and tries to run the tests in place - which fails due to the setup magic rearranging the package structure. To force nosetests to build before execution, add the flag

```
use_2to3 = True
```

to the setup.py command.

Note that if you DON'T want 2to3 to run (say you have some python2.7 modules you are happy with that break), this won't work.

In the end, everything stays the same except setup.py, which looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'mypkg',
    packages = ['mypkg','unittests'],
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    use_2to3 = True,
    )
```